# C# Reflection Problem

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I'm having the following problem when using reflection.

The following statement evaluates to false:

```
object[] attributes = someType.GetCustomAttributes(true);

if (attributes[0] is NUnit.Framework.TestFixtureAttribute)
    return true;
```

However this evaluates to true:

```
object[] attributes = someType.GetCustomAttributes(true);

if (attributes[0].ToString() == "NUnit.Framework.TestFixtureAttribute")
    return true;
```

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Perhaps it's loading a different version of the assembly?

Compare `attributes[0].GetType().Assembly` with `typeof(NUnit.Framework.TestFixtureAttribute).Assembly`.

Just perform a reference type comparison - even if two `Assembly` instances have been loaded from the exact same file, if they're two separate instances, any types created from them will be distinct (making `is` fail).

Comment: typeof(NUnit.Framework.TestFixtureAttribute).Assembly yields

The type 'NUnit.Framework.TestFixtureAttribute' exists in both 'nunit.framework.dll' and 'nunit.framework.dll'

So I presume there are 2 versions of 'nunit.framework.dll' on my system.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The class you're testing has probably been built with a different version of nunit.framework.dll